# Discord Api : Good practices to save guilds in database with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, discord

I have an application which saves the user's guilds from the discord api in my database (mongoDB). I wonder if it's a good idea to replace the _id that create mongoDB for the id that the api send to me for each guild ? Could this have consequences for the indexes later ?

Comment: discord guild ids are unique, and they are long numbers(don save them as strings), there will be no problem to use them. If you use `_id : guild_id` you don't need another index, but if you use  `"guildid" : guildid` create an index on it to be fast on search